# Different maps have the same hashcode

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode

I have two **different** `Map`s, but they have the same hash code value:

```
    Map<String,Boolean> map1=new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("a", false);
    map1.put("b", true);
    map1.put("c", true);
    map1.put("d", true);
    map1.put("e", true);
    map1.put("f", false);
    map1.put("g", true);
    map1.put("k", false);
    Map<String,Boolean> map2=new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("a", false);
    map2.put("b", false);
    map2.put("c", false);
    map2.put("d", false);
    map2.put("e", true);
    map2.put("f", true);
    map2.put("g", false);
    map2.put("k", true);

    System.out.println(map1.hashCode()); //9595
    System.out.println(map2.hashCode()); //9595 --> should be different as the values are different!
```

The behavior of the `hashcode`  function is perfectly fine for me: if the map changes then, of course, the hashcode should change. If the values in the map are identical, then the hash code should be identical. However, the standard hash **obviously leads to collisions of similar objects**. **How can I calculate a hash for these two maps?**

I tried to use the HashCodeBuilder from `org.apache.commons`

```
System.out.println(new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31)
        .append(map1.values())
        .toHashCode());

System.out.println(new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31)
        .append(map2.values())
        .toHashCode());

System.out.println(new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31)
        .append(map4.values())  //identical values as map2
        .toHashCode());
```

Which returns for map1, map2 AND map4 (which has the identical values als map2) a different hash. However, the hashes of maps with the same values should be identical....

Comment: hashCode() returns an int. There are only 2^32 different ints. But there are an infinity of potential map contents. So of course, some contents will lead to the same hash. You shouldn't care whether hashes are equal or not. A hash is not an identity. What matters is that two equal objects have the same hash, and that hashes are not too badly distributed. If you use a hashCode as a unique key to identify an object, then you need to change your strategy, because it's just wrong.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.codercowboy.com/2018/10/17/java-hashmap-hashcode-not-unique-with-string-keys-and-values/) for an explanation and workaround. Short version: Java's `hashCode` implementation for `Map` doesn't combine the individual element codes in a very good way.

Comment: @luk2302 that's an incorrect explanation. equals is not more expensive than hashCode. It's actually often cheaper, since it can short-circuit. The point of hashCode is to tremendously reduce the number of potentially equal candidates in a hash-based collection, by only comparing those which are in the same bucket, which is itself deduced from the hashCode.

Comment: @David Schwarzt: could you write a answer so that I can accept it? I know the problem with a hash and I was looking for a work around which David Schwartz provided!

Answer (score 1):

> The behavior of the hashcode function is perfectly fine for me: if the map changes then, of course, the hashcode should change.

Emphasis on *should change*, not must. The only requirement to `hashCode` regarding that is that the hash must be equal if the values are equal. It does **not** give any requirements about what should happen if the values are different. It suggests that the hash should be different, but that is only a suggestion and there are many cases in practice where `hashCode` can not follow that suggestion.

Your approach is flawed. You must not make any assumptions about hashes for different values, especially not that they are different.

If you have a hash-collision, for example in a hash-based collection, you must use `equals` as second step to check if it actually is the same element or just a collision for two different elements.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) of `Object#hashCode`:

> It is **not required** that if two objects are **unequal** according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects **may improve the performance** of hash tables.

---

There is of course a technical reason for this. Hashing is about representing something potentially very big by something rather small.

In this particular case, representing any `Object` by a single `int`. There are only `2^32` different integer values but infinite many different `Map` setups. So it is just impossible to have a different `int` hash for each of them.

More on this topic at [Wikipedia#Hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).